# Reduce number of times I call a function dependent on the selectizeInput box

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I developed a small shiny app:
[app](http://ashermetzger.shinyapps.io/rain)

The app plots the rain for stations that are chosen in the selectizeInput.
It goes to an external server for the data each time a station is add or removed.

At the moment, it fetches the data from an external server for all the stations regardless if they remain in the list or not. This adds time and computation that are not needed.
My question is how do I reduce the need to get data that is already present?

because I can't present the real app I created a reproducible app to illustrate my code flow:

```
#data
id <- as.numeric(1:26)
names(id) <- letters

#dataframe function
get.rain.data <- function(id){
  print(id)
  vec <- 1:100
  id <- as.numeric(id)
  print(id)
  df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(id,function(i)
    tibble(x=vec,y=vec*i+vec^2*i,
    id=as.factor(rep(i,length(vec))))))
  return(df)
}

#plot function
plot.rain <- function(df){
  print(df)
  p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,group=id))+
    geom_line(aes(color=id),size=0.6)
  ggplotly(p,height=700)
}


#### UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("Rain Intensities and Cumulative Rain")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Check rain with info from
               IMS.gov.il"),
      selectizeInput("var", h3("Select station"), 
                     choices = id,
                     multiple = T,
                     selected = 4)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("rain")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    get.rain.data(input$var)
  })

  output$rain <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$var)
    plot.rain(dataInput())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the needed code. Everywhere you want to use results from input$var call DataInput() instead. By creating the reactive dataInput function, it will be called when the input$var is updated

```
# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    get.rain.data(input$var)
  })

  output$rain <- renderPlotly({
    plot.rain(dataInput())
  })
}
```

I think what you need is to cache values so that they are only queried once. You may want look at the memoise package the can automatically do this for you.

https://github.com/r-lib/memoise

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe my question wasn't clear: When the app loads the "d" line is shown. If I add more choices, e.g. "d", "a", "b" the function will not only add "a" and "b" but also run "d" again. Is there an option of reducing this need? In this case it isn't an issue because the function is simple and runs fast but not so in the real app.